# Size of an unknown array in C

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures, memory-management, size

I am trying to find size of an array in C at two different contexts. One is after immediate declaration of array. Another is at after I pass that array to a function. The length is shown different at different contexts. I didn't get the logic why is it happening. Take a look at my code.

```
LLNode* createLL(int* arr)
{
    printf("%d ", sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int));

    LLNode* head=(LLNode *)malloc(sizeof(LLNode));
    head->data = arr[0];
    head->next = NULL;
    int i=0, n=11;
    for(i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        insertNode(head, arr[i]);
    }
    return head;
}

int main()
{
    int a[12] = {5,5,55,6,1,5,5,48,5,4,8};
    printf("%d ", sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));
    LLNode* head = createLL(a);
    // insertNode(head, 87);
    // printLL(head);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is : 12 2.

The length is shown as 2 in the function no matter what my size of the array is. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: You can't use `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)` with a pointer. You need to pass the size to the function.

Comment: Hemanth, "Another is at after I pass that array to a function."  --> `createLL(int* arr)` is receiving a _pointer_, not an _array_.  `sizeof(arr)` is the size of a _pointer_, not the size of an _array_.  Since `main()` well calculated the size with `sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)`, why not also pass that quotient to a new `createLL(int* arr, size_t size)`?

Comment: Aside: simplify `LLNode* head=(LLNode *)malloc(sizeof(LLNode));` into `LLNode* head = malloc(sizeof head[0]);`.

Comment: Then how can I find size of the array in the function createLL?